# Laravel: mocking service class in job

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I want to mock a service class for a test, but I can not.

##### My test

```
protected function setUp() : void
{
    parent::setUp();

    Queue::fake();

    $this->client = $this->createClient();
}

private function callJob()
{
    CreateBrevoContactJob::dispatch($this->client);
}

/** @test */
public function it_calls_create_brevo_contact_api_endpoint()
{
    $this->mock(ContactsApi::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
        $mock->shouldReceive('createContact')->once();
    });

    $this->callJob();
}
```

#### My job

```php
class CreateBrevoContactJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public Client $client;
    private ContactsApi $brevo;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     * @param Client $client
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Client $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
        $this->brevo = (new Brevo())->getContactInstance();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->brevo->createContact((new ClientBrevoContactAdapter($this->client))->convert());
        // create new contact (api)
        // create BrevoContact from brevo api instance
    }
}
```

##### `Brevo.php`

```php
class Brevo extends Model
{
    private Configuration $config;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->config = Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setApiKey('api-key', env('BREVO_API_KEY'));
    }

    public function getContactInstance(): ContactsApi
    {
        return new ContactsApi(
            new Client(),
            $this->config
        );
    }
}
```

##### Test result

> 1. Tests\Unit\Jobs\CreateBrevoContactJobTest::it_calls_create_brevo_contact_api_endpoint
>    Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method createContact() from Mockery_2_SendinBlue_Client_Api_ContactsApi should be called
>    exactly 1 times but called 0 times.

Comment: But you are using `new` everywhere, you have to tell Laravel to resolve it using `resolve(class)` or `app(class)`, else, PHP will always resolve, and will never use the mock definition (defined on Laravel's Service Container). Check out my profile, I do have links to other questions and answers about testing, one should help you